# In Qt Quick application, Element mess up in developed application run on full HD phone

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, screen-resolution

I developed application on Qt Quick, I arranged size and space of all elements based on semi HD screen, It looks good in every semi HD phone, but when I try to run this application on full HD phone, all elements are mess up and look messy.

*I tested my application on two different android phone, one is Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo(Display Resolution 480x800) and another one is Samsung Galaxy S4(Display Resolution 1080x1920). As shown in bellow image, one is good looking which one is snap-shot of Samsung galaxy grand neo, and second image is messy which one is snap-shot of Samsung galaxy S4.*

***In short my main problem related to Display resolution, when it change my application look messy.***

Please help to set elements for both semi HD and full HD phone.

MainForm.ui.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item {
    id: item1
    width:640 //1080
    height:480 //1920

    property alias button3: button3
    property alias button2: button2
    property alias button1: button1

    Button {
        id: button2
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/12
        text: qsTr("Press Me 2")
        anchors.left: button1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 6
        anchors.top: image1.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 108
    }

    Button {
        id: button3
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/12
        text: qsTr("Press Me 3")
        anchors.left: button2.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 6
        anchors.top: image1.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 108
    }

    Button {
        id: button1
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/12
        text: qsTr("Press Me 1")
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 48
        anchors.top: image1.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 108
    }

    Text {
        id: text1
        width: parent.width/3.2
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: _myClass.response
        anchors.top: textEdit2.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 162
        font.italic: true
        font.bold: true
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        style: Text.Normal
        font.pointSize: parent.height/33
    }

    Text {
        id: text2
        width: parent.width/6.5
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("Device Name :")
        anchors.top: text6.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 2
        font.bold: true
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
    }

    Text {
        id: text3
        width: parent.width/6.5
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("MacAddress :")
        anchors.top: text2.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 2
        font.bold: true
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
    }

    Text {
        id: text4
        width: parent.width/3.2
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: _myClass.response2
        anchors.top: text1.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 162
        font.italic: true
        font.bold: true
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/33
    }

    Text {
        id: text5
        width: parent.width/6.5
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("Username :")
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 6
        font.bold: true
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
    }

    Text {
        id: text6
        width: parent.width/6.5
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#fbfbfb"
        text: qsTr("Password :")
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        anchors.top: text5.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 6
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: textEdit1
        width: parent.width/3.2
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("Text Edit")
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 162
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: textEdit2
        width: parent.width/3.2
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("Text Edit")
        anchors.top: textEdit1.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 162
        font.underline: false
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
    }

    Image {
        id: image1
        width: parent.width/5.5
        height: parent.height/6.2
        sourceSize.height: 0
        sourceSize.width: 0
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 13
        source: "veejansh.png"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        z: -1
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#000000"
            }

            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#00239b"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQml 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: Screen.width //640//1920
    height: Screen.height //480//1080
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Open action triggered"));
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("E&xit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    MainForm {
        //width: parent.width
        //height: parent.height

        anchors.fill: parent

        function testing1(){
            _myClass.test1()
            //messageDialog.show(qsTr());
        }

        function testing2(){
            _myClass.test2()
            //messageDialog.show(qsTr("Hello!!!"));
        }

        button1.onClicked: testing1()
        button2.onClicked: testing2()
        button3.onClicked: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Button 3 pressed"))
    }

    MessageDialog {
        id: messageDialog
        title: qsTr("May I have your attention, please?")

        function show(caption) {
            messageDialog.text = caption;
            messageDialog.open();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

As shown in images in semiHD looks OK, but in fullHD it looks messy. This problem related only with QML file, so I share only qml code, if there is requirement of other data, please tell me.

Comment: Please edit the question and insert a full-resolution screenshot from the device. Use the image hosting built into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is very small, I have to set margin also, I have to set left margin and top margin depend on parent hight and width. I changed my code as show in bellow.

```
Button {
        id: button1
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/12
        text: qsTr("Press Me 1")
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 48
        anchors.top: image1.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: parent.height/5.92 //108
    }

    Text {
        id: text1
        width: parent.width/3.2
        height: parent.height/12.30
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: _myClass.response
        anchors.top: textEdit2.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.left: image1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: parent.width/2.96 //162
        font.italic: true
        font.bold: true
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        style: Text.Normal
        font.pixelSize: parent.height/33
    }
```

***anchors.leftMargin: parent.width/2.96*** we have to set this thing as per our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1 - In the `main.qml` file define the window size as the screen size of the device.

2 - Create a `qml` file, in this case called `Componente.qml`, with the `Item` inside it.

3 - In `Componente.qml` make the code you want. In this case I modified the code moving the rectangle that was at the end of the code to be created first and I put the elements inside it.

4 - Call the `Componente.qml` inside the `main.qml` and define its size as the parent size.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height

    Componente {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
    }
}
```

Componente.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item {
    id: item1

    property alias button3: button3
    property alias button2: button2
    property alias button1: button1

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        anchors.fill: parent
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#000000"
            }

            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#00239b"
            }
        }


        Button {
            id: button2
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/12
            text: qsTr("Press Me 2")
            anchors.left: button1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            anchors.top: image1.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 108
        }

        Button {
            id: button3
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/12
            text: qsTr("Press Me 3")
            anchors.left: button2.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            anchors.top: image1.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 108
        }

        Button {
            id: button1
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/12
            text: qsTr("Press Me 1")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 48
            anchors.top: image1.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 108
        }

        Text {
            id: text1
            width: parent.width/3.2
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: "Texto"
            anchors.top: textEdit2.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 162
            font.italic: true
            font.bold: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            style: Text.Normal
            font.pointSize: parent.height/33
        }

        Text {
            id: text2
            width: parent.width/6.5
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Device Name :")
            anchors.top: text6.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 2
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
        }

        Text {
            id: text3
            width: parent.width/6.5
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("MacAddress :")
            anchors.top: text2.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 2
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
        }

        Text {
            id: text4
            width: parent.width/3.2
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: "Texto"
            anchors.top: text1.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 162
            font.italic: true
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            font.pixelSize: parent.height/33
        }

        Text {
            id: text5
            width: parent.width/6.5
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Username :")
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 50
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
        }

        Text {
            id: text6
            width: parent.width/6.5
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#fbfbfb"
            text: qsTr("Password :")
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            anchors.top: text5.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            font.bold: true
            font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
        }

        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit1
            width: parent.width/3.2
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Text Edit")
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 50
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 162
            font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
        }

        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit2
            width: parent.width/3.2
            height: parent.height/12.30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Text Edit")
            anchors.top: textEdit1.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            anchors.left: image1.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 162
            font.underline: false
            font.pixelSize: parent.height/34.30
        }

        Image {
            id: image1
            width: parent.width/5.5
            height: parent.height/6.2
            sourceSize.height: 0
            sourceSize.width: 0
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 50
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 13
            source: "veejansh.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation along the code would certainly improve this answer

Comment: Please check again my question, I added some explanation and try your suggestion but still I face same problem related with different Display Resolution.

Comment: I don't have a device with full HD Resolution to test, so I tested it in a Android Emulator and it worked fine.